# R Plotly is showing extra random arrows while using subplot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I wrote a function to generate multiple graphs in plotly. In each of those graph, I am only adding annotations for last data point.

To plot all those graphs at once, I am using subplot function.
This however shows some extra arrows on the graph. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, where they are coming from, or how do I turn them off.
(Turning them white wouldn't be a solution as they are also problamatic in the sense that their position stays relatively constant if eg Y axis is formatted as %- they just dwarf everything)

[image]

Really appreciate some assistance with this.

```
library(plotly)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)


# A function to generate plots in the required format
plotbundlefunction<-function(data1,ttitle){
  mypalette <- c("#4E79A7","#F28E2B","#E15759","#76B7B2","#59A14F","#EDC948","#B07AA1","#FF9DA7","#9C755F","BAB0AC") %>% head(ncol(data1)-1)
  lineannot<-c()
  for(i in 2:ncol(data1)){  
    lineannot[[i]]<-list(x = tail(na.omit(data1 %>% select('ID',i)),n=1L)[['ID']], y = tail(na.omit(data1[[i]]),n=1L), text = tail(na.omit(data1[[i]]),n=1L),
                         font=list(color=mypalette[i-1]),xanchor = "left", bgcolor="#D4D8DF", showarrow = F)
  }
  
  p <- plot_ly()
  for(i in 2:ncol(data1)){
    p<-add_trace(p,x=data1[['ID']],y=data1[[i]],name=colnames(data1)[i], type='scatter', mode='lines')
  }
  p %>% layout(colorway=mypalette, annotations = lineannot) %>% return()
}

# Numerous dataframe representing snapshot at a point in time for same data characteristics
dflist<-list(
  KPI1 = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), Japan=c(100,98,97,95,94), Korea = c(100,97,94,91,87) , Laos=c(100,97,94,90,84)),
  KPI2 = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), Japan=c(5,7,8,9,3)      , Korea = c(6,8,7,9,5)       , Laos=c(7,5,5,2,1)),
  KPI3 = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5), Japan=c(78,89,56,48,92) , Korea = c(42,49,85,99,72)  , Laos=c(78,58,88,87,68))
)

#Iterate over a function that generates a separate graph for each columns across dataframes 
mainplotset<-lapply(1:length(dflist),function(s){
  plotbundlefunction(dflist[[names(dflist)[s]]],names(dflist)[s])
})

#Do a subplot to show all results 
subplot(mainplotset,nrows = 1,margin=0.05)
```

Comment: Tried your code, everything looks fine, no arrows.

Comment: Thanks for checking- did you use the subplot function or just mainplotset? The issue happens specifically with subplot, although everything looks fine in individual graphs contained in mainplotset

Comment: I see, didn't use `subplot`. I do see the arrows now

Comment: I answered your question with a workaround, but I just figured out where the extra essentially empty trace is coming from. It's even easier to fix than the workaround. In the for loop `for(i in 2:ncol...`  your first value of `i ` is 2, and you used `lineannot[[i]] <- ...`. Change that to `lineannot[[i - 1]] <- ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update based on your comment

As I pointed out in my comment after I already posted this answer, the actual solution is the revise the for statement that creates the annnotations. Instead of

```
for(i in 2:ncol(data1)){  
  lineannot[[i]] <- ...
```

It should be

```
for(i in 2:ncol(data1)){  
  lineannot[[i - 1]] <- ...
```

On to how I found the arrows...

I meant to include how I came up with the annotations traces, sorry about leaving that out!

I can't think of any way an arrow can get into a plot without annotations, so I knew where to start. So first, I set the subplot to an object and looked at whether `showarrow` was set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
plt <- subplot(mainplotset,nrows = 1,margin=0.05)

invisible(lapply(
  1:length(plt$x$layout$annotations),
  function(k) {
    res <- plt$x$layout$annotations[[k]]$showarrow
    message("arrow? ", k, " ", res)
  }
))
```

The default for `annotations` is `showarrow = TRUE`, so that's why your plots were returned with arrows.

#### Original answer

Such an odd error! I'm not sure how to prevent this error. (I'm still trying to figure that out.) In the meantime, I thought I could give you a way to fix it.

I used `lapply` to find out what traces were creating these arrows.

```
plt <- subplot(mainplotset, nrows = 1, margin = 0.05)

# arrow? 1 
# arrow? 2 FALSE
# arrow? 3 FALSE
# arrow? 4 FALSE
# arrow? 5 
# arrow? 6 FALSE
# arrow? 7 FALSE
# arrow? 8 FALSE
# arrow? 9 
# arrow? 10 FALSE
# arrow? 11 FALSE
# arrow? 12 FALSE
```

When I looked at the traces that didn't indicate true or false, there was nothing in the traces except `xref` and `yref`.

To remove them:

```
plt$x$layout$annotations <- plt$x$layout$annotations[c(-1, -5, -9)]
plt
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! you're amazing! I was so lost on graphs I didn't even look into the loop.

Can you also please share the snippet on how to use lapply to find the arrow? I'm curious to learn

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that information. Sorry about that!